# How would I allow the user to input an x so that the program returns the divided difference y value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that sketches the graph of the interpolation of a function using divided differences. However, I want to know how would I allow the user to input an x value so that the program would return the corresponding y value of the divided difference?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def Polynomial (t,X,Y):
    A=Y
    B=Y
    n=len(A)-1
    C=[]
    for j in range (1,n):
        A= list(B)
        C.append(B[j-1])
        for i in range(j,n):
                B[i]=(A[i]-A[i-1])/(X[i]-X[i-j])
    C.append(B[n-1])
    S=0
    P=1
    for k in range(n):
        S=S+P*C[k]
        P=P*(t-X[k])
    return S

X=[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]
Y=[1/26,1/17,1/10,1/5,1/2,1,1/2,1/5,1/10,1/17,1/26]
I= np.arange(-5, 5, 1)
plt.plot(X,Y,"ro")
plt.plot(I,Polynomial(I,X,Y), "b")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `input()` to ask for input from the user, then assign the input to a variable and pass that variable to to function;

```
x = input()
```